# How to change the font family to default for math codes in beamer?

Tags: beamer, fonts

My compiled math font family is not like a default one(e.g., the font used in MahtJaX), but it is same as the text font family. My example code and it's complied one are shown below.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{palatino}

\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{serif}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{definition}
Let $R\subseteq S\timesT$ be a relation.\break
The domain of R is defined as:\break
$\operatorname{Dom} \left({\mathcal R}\right) := \left\{{s \in S: \exists t \in T: \left({s, t}\right) \in \mathcal R}\right\}$\break
and can be denoted $\operatorname{Dom} \left({\mathcal R}\right)$.
\end{definition}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]
This definition is from [the webpage](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Domain_(Set_Theory)#Definition) of Proofwiki.
How to change the font family to default for math codes in beamer?

Comment: Load the professional font theme to stop `beamer` changing the fonts. `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`

Comment: @cfr Nice. It worked nicely. But, may I ask one more simple question? I want to right the context of a definition right next to the label "Definition". How do I do that? (In the example above, the contexts are starting in the next line. It automatically make a `\break`.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of this echoes Herbert's answer but I posted it as a comment 8 minutes prior to that answer and so claim this answer is legitimate ;). (But I will remove it if Herbert objects or if anybody else, not being Herbert, both objects and can give me a good reason why they have a right to object despite not being Herbert.)

## Original Question

`\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` prevents `beamer` from overwriting your fonts and is therefore needed to use specified font packages.

`palatino` is deprecated, however. `l2tabuen` recommends this replacement:

```
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}% uncomment these if required
\usepackage{courier}
```

[image: URW Palatino look-alike]

An alternative would be to use TeX Gyre's Pagella, for example.

## Second Question

Since this is a different question it should really be a different question. However, you could use the `description` environment rather than the `definition` environment here. `definition` always starts a new line for the main part of the definition. (The name of the term can go on the same line but the definition itself starts below.) While this could obviously be changed, it seems to me there are simpler options. For example:

```
\begin{description}
  \item[Definition] Definition goes here.
\end{description}
```

[image: A definition of a different kind...]

## The Code

```
\documentclass[xcolor=x11names,compress]{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
% \usepackage{palatino}% is obsolete - see l2tabu (or l2tabuen) for details
\usepackage{mathpazo}
% \usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}% uncomment these if required
% \usepackage{courier}

\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usefonttheme{serif}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\begin{description}
  \item[Definition] Let $R\subseteq S\times T$ be a relation.\break
  The domain of R is defined as:\break
  $\operatorname{Dom} \left({\mathcal R}\right) := \left\{{s \in S: \exists t \in T: \left({s, t}\right) \in \mathcal R}\right\}$\break
  and can be denoted $\operatorname{Dom} \left({\mathcal R}\right)$.
\end{description}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you provide information on the different packages? I have tried to comment out some to see the effects and found, that `\usepackage{courier}` doesn't do anything for me. Moreover, is there a list of viable packages?

Comment: @gr4nt3d `courier` will have an effect only if your document includes sans-serif text and not only serif. E.g. `\textsf{}` or `[\sffamily }`. The same with `helvet`. If you never use sans, loading these is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

```
\useinnertheme{default}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\let\familydefault\rmdefault
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: What is the code `\let\familydefault\rmdefault` affects on?

Comment: Sets the main font roman (serif)

Comment: @Herbert I had a problem of proper math symbols typesetting, and I asked [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/325817/2288). Then I found your answer here to use `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`  which fixes my problem. I wonder what is the difference between using `professionalfonts` as a class option and using it as a font theme as you did here?

Comment: there is no difference. But it makes more sense to use it as shown, because all other themes must be loaded in the same way.

Comment: @Herbert I understand; I found that loading `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` makes me not need to load `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`; it seems to implicitly loads `serif` font for math environment.  Does it mean I should follow one way or both are good?

Comment: "professionalfonts"  means that the complete font setting is done by _you_ and _not_ `beamer`. This is the reason why another fonttheme makes no sense if you have `professionalfonts` set.