# operatorname does not work for Greek capitals in Beamer with T1 font encoding

Tags: beamer, math-operators, greek

I cannot define `operatorname` for `\Delta` when line `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` is added into preamble. For `\delta` or without T1 things seem to work properly. But for the following example I get ‘´ d’ instead of ‘∆ d’.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % without this line operatorname works properly

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    $\operatorname{\Delta}d=1.$
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} prevents beamer from overwriting your
>   fonts and is therefore needed to use specified font packages - [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/193290)

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\begin{document}    
\begin{frame}
    $\operatorname{\delta}d=1$

    $\operatorname{\Delta}d=1$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]