# Beamer/LuaLaTeX: How to properly typeset math symbols?

Tags: beamer, luatex, math-fonts

The output of the following code wrongly typesets `\tilde{T}` in the second equation; how can it be fixed?

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools,bm}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

\begin{align}
    \vm{\Phi}_{,\gamma}^T & = \vm{P}_{,\gamma}^T\pbm{x}\,\vm{A}^{-1}\,\vm{B} = \left\{ \begin{array}{c c c c}
    \phi_1 & \phi_2 & \cdots & \phi_n 
    \end{array} \right\}_{\left(1 \times n\right)},\\
    %
    \mathbf{\tilde{T}_s} & =%
    \left\{%
    \begin{array}{ccccc}
    T_1 & T_2 & \cdots & T_n & \bm{0}_{\left( 1 \times m \right)} 
    \end{array}%
    \right\}^T
\end{align}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace `\mathbf{\tilde{T}_s}` with `\widetilde{\mathbf{T}}_{\mathbf{s}}`. (Observe that the `T` and `s` characters are set in bold, whereas the "tilde" diacritic does not.)

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[professionalfonts]{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\usepackage{mathtools,bm}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black}
\newcommand\vm[1]{\bm{#1}}
\newcommand\pbm[1]{\left(\mathbf{#1}\right)}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
$\mathbf{\tilde{T}_s}$ vs.\ $\widetilde{\mathbf{T}}_s$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Additionally, is there any document that shows the alternatives to the typical symbol commands? I don't prefer to ask again whenever I stumble across incorrect symbol command.

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - I'm not sure what you have in mind in terms of "the alternatives to the typical symbol commands". For starters, what are "typical symbol commands"? FWIW, a rule -- which I believe is very much in the typographic mainstream -- that I apply to my own working papers is *never* to bold diacritical symbols such as `\tilde`, `\hat`, `\widetilde`, `\widehat`, and `\bar`.

Comment: Thanks for advising not to bold these symbols. On the other hand, in my question for example, `\tilde` is replaced by `\widetilde` to properly typeset it using lualatex. My inquiry is: are there other symbols that need to be replaced when typesetting using lualatex?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou - Regardless of whether one uses pdfLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, I believe it's a good idea to use `\widetilde` and `\widehat` instead of `\tilde` and `\hat` for most uppercase Latin and Greek letters. (Exceptions are `A`, `I`, and `L`; `S` and `C` are borderline cases.)